# Crop image in PHP without mask

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to crop an image in PHP from a square into a circle. I've seen a lot of solutions online that accomplish the getting of a circular image by masking the initial image and making the corners different colors. However, this is problematic, as setting the corners to transparent merely results in the initial square image for me. For example, the below code results in a circular image with pink corners

[image: result of below code]

```
$image_name = $_POST['filepath'];
$source_image = imagecreatefrompng($image_name);

$source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
$source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);
$dest_imagex = $_POST['width'];
$dest_imagey = $_POST['height'];
$dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);
imagealphablending($dest_image, true);
imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

// create masking
$mask = imagecreatetruecolor($source_imagex, $source_imagey);
$mask = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);
$pink = imagecolorallocate($mask, 255, 0, 255);
imagefill($mask, 0, 0, $pink);
$black = imagecolorallocate($mask, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($mask, $black);
imagefilledellipse($mask, $dest_imagex/2, $dest_imagey/2, $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $black);
imagecopy($dest_image, $mask, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);
imagecolortransparent($dest_image, $pink);
imagejpeg($dest_image, NULL);
```

Is there a way to crop an image in PHP such that the edges are actually removed?

Comment: What's wrong with using CSS for this? `border-radius: 50%` should achieve what you need.

Comment: I'm interfacing with iOS so I need to return just the circular image

Comment: Then what's wrong with: `cell.yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.yourImageView.frame.size.height /2;
cell.yourImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.yourImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0;`?

Comment: JPEGs don't support transparency. Output PNGs instead

Comment: I have never ran across a circular image, and I've done quite a bit of image work.  You need to keep the image data rectangular and either use transparency or as BenM suggested, CSS. Or, take your background and combine it with your image to make a composite.

Comment: Thanks @onetrickpony - outputting PNGs fixed it!

Comment: @BenM I was previously performing all of the cropping in iOS, but it was very performance intensive, so I'd rather take care of it server-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your corner to transparent and save it as a png (you can use a php library like wideimage or imagemagick, it will do this easily for you). An image file is always rectangular, if it has another shape it's because the other parts are transparent.

Answer (score 0):

fyi, to make it a png...
first change to this:

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
```

and then this(at the end of your code):

```
imagepng($dest_image, NULL);  //instead of imagejpeg()
```